# variable structure in json data source

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks

thanks for your time.

I have a dataframe in pyspark in Databricks that reads json. The data from the source does not always have the same structure, sometimes the '**emailAddress**' field does not appear, causing me the error **"org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve ...".**

I have tried to solve by applying a **Try-Except** function in this way:

```
try:
  df_json = df_json.select("responseID", "surveyID", "surveyName","timestamp", "customVariables.Id_Cliente", "timestamp", "responseSet", "emailAddress")

except ValueError:
  None
```

But it does not work for me, it returns the same error that I mentioned.

I am even trying to take another alternative but without results:

```
 if 'Id_Cliente' in s_fields:  
  try:
    df_json = df_json.select("responseID", "surveyID", "surveyName","timestamp", "customVariables.Id_Cliente", "timestamp", "responseSet", "emailAddress")
  except ValueError:
    df_json = df_json.select("responseID", "surveyID", "surveyName","timestamp", "customVariables.Id_Cliente", "timestamp", "responseSet")
```

Please help me with some idea to control this situation? I need to stop the execution of my notebook when it **does not find the field in the structure**, otherwise (it finds the emailAddress variable) to **continue processing.**

From already thank you very much.

Greetings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're catching `ValueError` while the exception is `AnalysisException`, that's why it doesn't work.

```py
from pyspark.sql.utils import AnalysisException

try:
    df.select('xyz')
except AnalysisException:
    print(123)
```